# OpenMP atomic compare and swap

Tags: openmp, atomic

I have a shared variable `s` and private variable `p` inside parallel region.

How can I do the following atomically (or at least better than with `critical` section):

```
if ( p > s )
    s = p;
else
    p = s;
```

I.e., I need to update the global maximum (if local maximum is better) or read it, if it was updated by another thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenMP 5.1 introduced the `compare` clause which allows compare-and-swap (CAS) operations such as

```c
#pragma omp atomic compare
if (s < p) s = p;
```

In combination with a `capture` clause, you should be able to achieve what you want:

```c
int s_cap;

// here we capture the shared variable and also update it if p is larger
#pragma omp atomic compare capture
{
   s_cap = s;
   if (s < p) s = p;
}

// update p if the captured shared value is larger
if (s_cap > p) p = s_cap;
```

The only problem? The 5.1 spec is very new and, as of today (2020-11-27), none of the widespread compilers, i.e., those available on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org), supports OpenMP 5.1. See [here](https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools/) for a more or less up-to-date list. Adding `compare` is still listed as an unclaimed task on Clang's OpenMP page. GCC is still working on full OpenMP 5.0 support and the `trunk` build on Godbolt doesn't recognise `compare`. Intel's oneAPI compiler may or may not support it - it's not available on Godbolt and I can't get it to compile OpenMP code.

Your best bet for now is to use `atomic capture` combined with a compiler-specific CAS atomic, possibly in a loop.

Comment: But, even like this you still have a race condition, if you have a thread updating 's' within the "pragma omp atomic compare capture" and another already doing if (s_cap > p)

Comment: `s_cap` captures the value of `s` at the time the atomic construct runs. If `p` was larger, `s` is updated inside the atomic and `(s_cap > p)` after it is false, so `p` remains unchanged. If `p` was lower, `s` is not updated but `p` is updated to the value of `s_cap`, i.e., the value `s` had during the execution of the atomic. The end result is the same as executing `if (p > s) s = p; else p = s;` in a critical section.

Comment: Yep, thanks, now I get it. I still have a hard time imagining where having something like this code actually makes sense (the OP example). Unless within a ordered constructor.

Comment: @dreamcash I have multiple threads searching for global max iteratively. Each new global max reduces search space for each thread. So if "this" thread found new max, I want to tell it to other threads. If global max was updated by another thread, "this" thread wants to get new global max to narrow "this" thread's search space

Comment: If you're after the max reduction, at least time the code using a reduction clause. You can also use a reduction clause if you're really after the location of the max. Its hard to see how knowing a running value helps to reduce the computation in other threads... Show us some real code!